# angular select first option value for mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am working on creating custom directive that work on both MatAutocomplete and MatSelect to select first option if required.
any help will be a great for me to complete it.

Here is my attempt to make it work.
i simply use MatAutocomplete, MatSelect injector to access value of it and observe options `change` prop to render but some time it work and some time it not, it also cause problem when use in `ngFor` loop.

```
@Directive({ selector: '[msg91AutoSelectDropdown]' })
export class AutoSelectDropDownDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    /**
     * FromControl to assign value if condition meet in ngAfterContentInit.
     */
    @Input() control: any;

    /**
     * Hold material component to get options from it.
     */
    private selectedMaterialComponent: MatAutocomplete | MatSelect;
    private subject = new Subject();
    private subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(
        @Optional() private autoCompleteSelect: MatAutocomplete,
        @Optional() private matSelect: MatSelect,
        @Optional() private formControl: NgControl
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.selectedMaterialComponent = this.autoCompleteSelect || this.matSelect;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log('viewContentChildren', this.viewContentChildren);
        this.withServiceInjector();
        // this.withContentChildren();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.subject) {
            console.log('in destroy');
            // this.viewContentChildren.destroy();
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
            this.subject.next(true);
            this.subject.complete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use to get What ever instance is available from Dependency injector or from Input binding.
     * @returns FormControl
     */
    public whichFormControl(): FormControl {
        return this.formControl?.control || this.control;
    }

    public withServiceInjector() {
        // add listener to options change(after render all options)
        this.subscription = this.selectedMaterialComponent.options.changes
            .pipe((takeUntil(this.subject), distinctUntilChanged(isEqual)))
            .subscribe((changes) => {
                console.log('changes before', changes);
                if (changes.length) {
                    console.log('changes', changes);
                    // get form control to operate on.
                    const whichControl = this.whichFormControl();
                    // check validation existence (processed further only if control is required).
                    const checkValidatorExist = whichControl?.hasValidator(Validators.required);
                    // continue only if checkValidatorExist and changes length.
                    // && (changes.length === 1 || changes.length === 2)
                    // console.log('checkValidatorExist', checkValidatorExist);
                    // console.log('whichControl', whichControl)
                    if (checkValidatorExist) {
                        console.log('changes._results[1].value', changes._results?.[1]?.value);
                        // type cast particular result index value.
                        if (!!changes._results[0]?.value) {
                            if (whichControl instanceof FormControl) {
                                whichControl.setValue(changes._results[0].value);
                            }
                        } else if (!!changes._results[1].value) {
                            if (whichControl instanceof FormControl) {
                                whichControl.setValue(changes._results[1].value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: When would you trigger the autoselect for the first option? On mat select it could be after the view is rendered. But how about  the MatAutoComplete? when should the happen?

Comment: @MehyarSawas i use changes event to set value, so if there is option changes the event is emited (options.changes) and we set first value based on condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You just need to the code block inside the subscribe callback and put it in its own method and call the method immediately afterViewInit and the subscribe to the options.changes as you did and use your new method in callback.

Similar to:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const matComponent =
      this.matSelect ??
      (this.matAutocompleteTrigger
        ? this.matAutocompleteTrigger.autocomplete
        : undefined);

    // schedule the execution to ensure the options elements to be rendered
    asapScheduler.schedule(() => {
      this.handleAutoselect(matComponent);
    });

    matComponent.options.changes.subscribe(() =>
      this.handleAutoselect(matComponent)
    );
  }

  private handleAutoselect(matComponent) {
    if (!this.formControl.control.hasValidator(Validators.required)) return;

    this.formControl.control.setValue(matComponent.options.first.value);
  }
```

My [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gfcjux?file=src/app/autoselect.directive.ts)

**Explaied**

I did not look at the source code of the Mat Components, but probably the option.changes does not emit initially right after the view is rendered. So when there is no change on the options, your logic in the subscribe callback will not be executed. Calling your logic immediately in the afterViewInit will ensure executing the logic at the initail view render. I used rxjs::[asapScheduler](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/asapScheduler) to postpone the execution until the option elements are rendered. You could also use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) achieve this.
I my stackblitz example I have created a button to dynamically change the options, where you can see that the method is sucessfully executed after the button is clicked.

It is recommended to use [@Host](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#make-a-dependency-optional-and-limit-search-with-host) decorator to make sure that only the host mat component is injected in your directive an not any parent one on the dom tree.

Comment: on your stackblitz when we remove character by delete button on the mat autocomplete value will re allocate again with seted value

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what the problem is? What are you expecting and what is the outcome and when does it happen? I do not have a delete button im my example.

Comment: in stackblitz click on `change options` button then remove value from autocomplete you see same value populated agian (which we not want ).

Comment: This button is only for demonstration pupose and has nothing to do with the implementation of the directive. The directive works fine, or is not it?

Comment: I will just remove the button just to avoid confusion

Comment: still i am not able to remove `one` from mat autoselect.

Comment: there also one doubt about what if api response is `delayed` and asapScheduler run after current ``mAcrotask` complete.

Comment: If there is an API that influences the rendering of the options then this will be handled in options.changes

Comment: Because options.changes triggers each time you type a new value in the form control, the  handleAutoselect is called and will reset the value. I have added a check if the autocomplete isOpen do not update the value. Checkout my stackblitz again